Removing leading comments from column data to categorize data
How can I extract an SQL query from a string that has leading comments and return the query along with any comments after the query, while ignoring any comments before the query.
Example :
Input:
I) \n--comment
--comment
Select *from test
--comment
Output :
Select *from test
--comment
Ii) /comment/
Select*from test
Output :
Select*from test
Iii) /comment/
--comment
Select*from test
--comment
/Comment/
Output :
Select*from test
--comment
/Comment/
Example :
Input -



query string
categorization




Select*from abc



--select*from abc



--this is comment



/* This is comment



Select*from cde




Output should be as below currently I am getting non extract if it's coming with comment. I need to remove leading comment blocks only. Comment can be present in one line multiple lines, so different pattern can be with /*** or -- or /* etc.



query string
categorization




Select*from abc
Extract


--select*from abc
Extract


--this is comment



/* This is comment



Select*from cde
Extract



I have tried to check position of comment example, but it's not working as expected.
I have tried this to handle '--' but not working as I just need to remove leading comments single or multi-line comments :
WITH cleaned_data AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        -- Clean leading CR (chr(13)) and LF (chr(10))
        LTRIM(TRIM(LEADING chr(10) FROM TRIM(LEADING chr(13) FROM data))) AS cleaned_statement
    FROM abc
),
extracted_comments AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        -- Extract relevant SQL statement or comment
        CASE 
            -- If there is a single-line comment
            WHEN POSITION('--' IN cleaned_statement) > 0 THEN
                -- Extract everything from the first occurrence of '--' to the end of the line
                TRIM(SUBSTRING(cleaned_statement FROM POSITION('--' IN cleaned_statement)))
            -- If no comments found, return the cleaned statement
            ELSE cleaned_statement
        END AS final_statement
    FROM cleaned_data
)
SELECT final_statement
FROM extracted_comments
WHERE final_statement IS NOT NULL
  AND final_statement != '';


I need a clarifications -- are comments to be extracted from any type of SQL statements  LIKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc.,?

@JitendraLoyal-Yes,correct.Could be like \n--tests\n--comment\n select*from test or could be update could be insert etc.so different pattern present.

Please provide the table structure. Is it like the table has 2 columns, viz., id and query? Further can a statement is span multiple rows (with same id)? Lastly, can a row has multiple statements? Moreover, which all statements need to be covered? ALL SQL statements is a tough ask, and in that case, the problem needs to be differently.

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (data, '^.*(SELECT)', '\1', 'i')
FROM   abc;

We are using the regular expression to match all characters upto and including the SELECT keyword. We have put SELECT in parenthesis in the Regular Expression so that we can store the pattern, which is emitted as \1 in the 3rd parameter. The 4th parameter tells to ignore the case while matching regular expression.
